# 77 млн. больных умерло/умерли/умерла

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слов

Есть предложение:

> ... 77 млн. больных. Половина из них умерл(**о/и/а**).

Лично для меня, если говорить не задумываясь, звучит "умерло", но когда начинаю произносить остальные варианты, то они вроде тоже ничего, вот тут я и запутался.

Половина из них умерло. Так привычней.
Половина - она. Значит половина умерла?
Больные - они. Значит половина умерли?

Я бы мог объяснить это так:
77 млн. больных. Они умерли.
77 млн. больных. Половина из них умерло.

Comment: В заголовке: все умерли. В самом вопросе: половина умерла. Разница "всего лишь" в 38,5 млн человек.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны варианты. Розенталь пишет:

> Примечание. Формы согласования в роде со словами половина, четверть обусловлены контекстом... [§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

В Нацкорпусе встречается согласование сказуемого со словом *половина*, а также постановка сказуемого во мн. ч. (средний род найти не удалось, да и интуитивно я бы его не ставил). Причем выбор был сделан, скорее всего, каждым автором по своему индивидуальному вкусу.

Примеры:

> Спортивных кроссоверов Porsche Cayenne набралось в декларациях сенаторов восемь, причем **половина из них записана** на супруг чиновников. [Светлана Алеева. Сенаторы предпочитают Mercedes-Benz и BMW // Известия, 2014.04.15]
>
> Зато практически все покупатели (71%) берут с собой на осмотр 1–2 друзей, причем **половина из них зовут** тех знакомых, которые разбираются в машинах. [Светлана Алеева. Большинство москвичей продают свои машины самостоятельно // Известия, 2014.04.19]
>
> Однако **половина из них** в той или иной степени **снизили** расходы на рекламу. [Светлана Поворазнюк. Производители лекарств и БАДов тратились на рекламу больше всех // Известия, 2014.02.19]
>
> Было нанято пять кинозвезд первой величины для того, чтобы в истории про наркотики, секс и смерть они смотрели вдаль, рассуждали о высоких материях и **половина из них** в итоге **сложила** головы самым затейливым образом. [Марина Латышева. Упавший с лезвия: Майкл Фассбендер в «Советнике» Ридли Скотта // РБК Дейли, 2013.10.25]

Я бы из уважения и сочувствия к каждому умершему поставил сказуемое во мн. ч.:

**77 млн больных. Половина из них умерли.**

Примечание: После сокращения *млн* точка не ставится, хотя многие это правило нарушают.